# How to control the browser that has been opened by nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I want to know how to control the browser that has been opened? I’ve read the API docs, but I can't find the way to do it.

---

like java

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

or python

```py
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

But how to do this by nodejs (javascript) ???
I’m so confused

Comment: Have you looked into Puppeteer?

Comment: nope , does the Puppeteer work ?

Comment: I'll   have a look. It seems better than selenium

Comment: Take a look here:https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/getting-started/nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Taken from https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-setup-selenium-on-node-environment-ee33023da72d

> The script below will open a chrome browser, input a term, submit the
> form, and return the page title. If the test is successful, then it
> should print out Test passed

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
driver.get('http://www.google.com').then(function(){
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver\n').then(function(){
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
      console.log(title)
      if(title === 'webdriver - Google Search') {
         console.log('Test passed');
      } else {
         console.log('Test failed');
      }
     driver.quit();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The below step will help you :

```
require('chromedriver');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

 var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
    var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
    var options = new chrome.Options();
    options.options_["debuggerAddress"] = "127.0.0.1:9222";
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: This solution helped me launch my tests into a Chrome instance that I had started from the CLI
```/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome  --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome_dev_remote --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check```